# How to enable an item selection from selectbox in CKEditior4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor4 to prepare document templates. And then these templates are used to create documents, but also with CKEditor. So, I want to use in the template select items such as enum values, which value I can select later, in a document.

But editor doesn't allow me to select any value from form element. 
Is there any way to make this item active?

Or, maybe, there is any plugin, which provides same features?